# filter from a different hierarchy

Tags: filter, mdx

How can I filter an MDX query to show several sets of data with a filter to 
exclude certain ID numbers from a different hierarchy. For example below,
what would be the syntax for the NOT IN part?

```
SELECT [Measures].[Gross GAAP Par OS Amt] ON COLUMNS,
FILTER( 
   [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name] * [Policy].[Policy ID].[Policy ID],
   [Policy].[Policy ID].Members
    ****NOT IN [NEW_Policy].[Policy ID].AllMembers****
)
ON ROWS
FROM EXPOSURE
```

Thanks!

Comment: different hierarchy but the same dimension?

Comment: It's a different dimension

Comment: I think I would approach this by adding a flag into my data source view that says whether a fact's Policy member is/isn't also a valid NEW_Policy member, and then simply make that into a third dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not related then I'm doubtful about the following as I think the two arguments of `EXCEPT` need to be from the same dimension:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Gross GAAP Par OS Amt] ON COLUMNS,
   [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name] 
   * 
   EXCEPT(
     [Policy].[Policy ID].Members,
     [NEW_Policy].[Policy ID].Members
   )
ON ROWS
FROM EXPOSURE
```

---

EDIT. (Obviously untested - if transferred to AdvWks example then easier to test)

Another attempt, this is more complex than in `sql`:

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[PolicyName] AS
     [Policy].[Policy ID].currentmember.membervalue
   MEMBER [Measures].[NEWPolicyName] AS
     [NEW_Policy].[Policy ID].currentmember.membervalue
   MEMBER [Measures].[DoTheyMatch] AS
     iif(
       [Measures].[PolicyName] = [Measures].[NEWPolicyName]
       ,1 
       ,null
     )  
   SET [MATCHES] AS
     NONEMPTY(
       [Policy].[Policy ID].Members
       *
       [NEW_Policy].[Policy ID].Members
       , [Measures].[DoTheyMatch]  
     )    
SELECT 
   [Measures].[Gross GAAP Par OS Amt] 
 ON 0,
   [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name] 
   * 
   EXCEPT(
     [Policy].[Policy ID].Members * [NEW_Policy].[Policy ID].Members,
     [MATCHES]
   )
 ON 1
FROM EXPOSURE
```